# Sending from whitelisted addresses is minting new tokens?

Tags: solidity

it seems to me that when you try to send tokens from the whitelisted(excluded from fee) addresses it seems to be minting new tokens so its not deducted from the sender(hence kind of minting new tokens since the supply is also increasing when these transfer happen). I wanted to ask(since im suspecting on this part code being the issue), what does this part of function do?

If _isExcludedFromFee[sender] is false it does those 2 transfers below, right? if its True(meaning the address is whitelisted) what does it do based on the code that is here?

```
    function _transferStandard(address sender, address recipient, uint256 tAmount) private {
    (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee, uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 charity, uint256 tLiquidity) = _getValues(tAmount);
    _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
    _rOwned[recipient] = _rOwned[recipient].add(rTransferAmount);
    _takeLiquidity(tLiquidity);
    _charity(charity);
    _reflectFee(rFee, tFee);
     if(!_isExcludedFromFee[sender])
    emit Transfer(sender, charityAdd, charity);

    emit Transfer(sender, recipient, tTransferAmount);
}
```

Thanks in advance and sorry if this is a dumb question.

p.s. i am not the owner of the token, i only hold some of it as an investor